# How to to build/simulate Toffoli gate using CSWAP (Fredkin) gates?

Tags: quantum-gate

I have seen a question about the other way (CSWAP from CCNOT). Both are 3 qubit gates.

Is there a way to simulate CCnot from Fredkin gates?

Comment: @CraigGidney is that answer even correct ? I remember reading somewhere that it IS possible. Also your answer does not point out what is wrong with the circuit given by OP... Thanks

Comment: Their circuit is wrong because it doesn't restore the ancilla qubits. It leaks information, which will prevent interference from working correctly later.

Comment: @CraigGidney, ok, I see why their circuit is wrong. Thanks. But can you develop a bit on the part where you mentioned might work logically but not physically?

Comment: If you use a dual rail encoding where logical 0 is physical 01 and logical 1 is physical 10 then a physical cswap can implement the logical toffoli, because there's no need to change the number of physical 1s.